# reverse function doesn't reverse the referenced string of a class instantiation

Tags: c++, string, inheritance, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the string from the FunnyNumber class. The problem is that when I call the method reverse in main on f2, it doesn't reverse the f2 string. But when I print out the reversed string from the reverse method implementation, it works. Also I overloaded the << operator to print out the string value in the class Number which is inherited in FunnyNumber class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Number {
public:
  // Make a number with value 0
  Number();
  // Make a number with value val
  Number(string val);

  // Get the number's value
  virtual string getValue() const;

  // Print this number to the stream
  virtual void print(ostream& stream) const;

  // Read this number from the stream
  virtual void read(istream& stream);

  // Overload the insertion operator
  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const Number& n);

  // Overload the extraction operator
  friend istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Number& n);

protected:
  string value;
};

#endif 


Number::Number()
{
  value = "";
}
Number::Number(string args)
{
  value = args;
}
string Number::getValue()const
{
  return value;
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const Number& n)
{
  n.print(outs);
  return outs;
}
void Number::print(ostream& stream)const
{
  stream << getValue();
}
void Number::read(istream& stream)
{
  stream >> value;
}
istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Number& n)
{
  n.read(ins);
  return ins;
}

#ifndef FUNNYNUMBER_H
#define FUNNYNUMBER_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"Number.h"
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;

class FunnyNumber : public Number 
{
public:
    FunnyNumber();
    FunnyNumber(string val);
    virtual string operator+(const FunnyNumber &other)const;
    virtual bool operator==(const FunnyNumber &other)const;
    void reverse();
    int find_first_not_this(char a);

protected:
    string value;

};
#endif // !FUNNYNUMBERS_H

FunnyNumber::FunnyNumber()
{
    value = "";
}

FunnyNumber::FunnyNumber(string val) : Number(val)
{
    value = val;
}

string FunnyNumber::operator+ (const FunnyNumber& other)const
{
    return getValue() + other.getValue();
}
int FunnyNumber::find_first_not_this(char a)
{
    int pos = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
    {
        if(value[i] != a)
        {
            pos = i;
            return pos;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
bool FunnyNumber::operator==(const FunnyNumber& other)const
{
    bool isEqual = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < other.getValue().length(); i++) 
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < getValue().length(); j++) 
        {
            if(getValue()[j] == other.getValue()[i])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            isEqual = found;
            return isEqual;
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}

void FunnyNumber::reverse()
{
    std::reverse(value.begin(), value.end());
    value.erase(0, find_first_not_this('0'));
}


#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include "FunnyNumber.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   FunnyNumber f2;
   f2 = FunnyNumber("223");
   f2.reverse();
   cout<<"Reversed value "<<f2<<endl;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

output is 223 instead of 322

Comment: How your operator `<<` is implemented?

Comment: value inside class number never was changed to the reverse of 223. since the overloaded operator << is getting its `value` from `class number`

Comment: what can i do to fix this?

Comment: @tildawn28 did you see the edit I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FunnyNumber` stores the value twice, once in a subobject of type `Number`, and once in `string FunnyNumber::value`.

Your `reverse` function modifies the second one, but doesn't have any effect on the `Number` base subobject.  And then the only output function you call is working on the `Number` base subobject, and knows nothing about `string FunnyNumber::value`.  That's why what is printed is not the result of reversal.

Comment: So to fix it I should overload the operator << in the FunnyNumber class too?

Comment: @tildawn28: That would be *a* solution, probably not the best one, because it means that any other circumstance that `FunnyNumber` is used in place of a `Number`, the reversed string won't be used.  But it's hard to talk about better solutions since you haven't shown the `Number` source code.

Comment: @tildawn28: Ok, all you need to do is remove `protected: string value;` from `FunnyNumber`, which is hiding the one inside `Number`.  Once you do, your reversal function will change `string Number::value` in the base subobject of `FunnyNumber`, affecting everything that uses a `FunnyNumber` polymorphically, including the `operator<<`.

Comment: This is way better than my solution +1.

Answer (score 0):

the overloaded operator << is a friend function on the Number class and friend functions are not [inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304490/7868736).

```
class Number {
public:
  // Make a number with value 0
  Number();
  // Make a number with value val
  Number(string &val);

  // Get the number's value
  virtual string getValue() const;

  // Print this number to the stream
  virtual void print(ostream& stream) const;

  // Read this number from the stream
  virtual void read(istream& stream);

  // Overload the insertion operator
  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const Number& n);

  // Overload the extraction operator
  friend istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Number& n);

protected:
  string *value;
};
Number::Number()
{
    value = NULL;
}
Number::Number(string &args)
{
  value = &args;
}
string Number::getValue()const
{
  return *value;
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const Number& n)
{
  n.print(outs);
  return outs;
}
void Number::print(ostream& stream)const
{
  stream << getValue();
}
void Number::read(istream& stream)
{
  stream >> *value;
}
istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Number& n)
{
  n.read(ins);
  return ins;
}
```

Comment: oh ok I see for some reason I thought friend functions were inherited too

Comment: Friend functions aren't inherited, but they will be used for instances of derived classes.  The bug is caused by something else.

Comment: this is what I came up with you can make the value in class number a pointer. tell me if this works